# What is a product of exact sequences?

Tags: exact-sequence, abelian-categories

I am trying to prove that $Seq(A)$, the category of short exact sequences of an Abelian category $A$, is additive. To do so, I need to show that products and coproducts exist and coincide. However, I am not sure what a product of exact sequences looks like.

Comment: Take your most naive guess and see if you can prove that it works.

Comment: Alternatively, realize that $Seq(A)$ is a subcategory of a functor category.

Comment: We know Seq(A) is a full subcategory of the category of all complexes.